# How to do a linebreak for every X number of boxes in a foreach loop

Tags: php, html, css, for-loop, foreach

Here is the code:

```
<div>
    <?php foreach($treatments as $treatment) 
    { ?>
        <a href="/offers/treatmentForm/<?= $treatment->treatment_name ?>">
            <button class = "btn btn-info menu_button">
                <div class = "treatment_box">
                    <p><span style="color: rgb(136, 136, 136); font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;"><?=($treatment->treatment_name)?></span></p>
                    <img class = "treatment_img" src= <?= ($treatment->icon_url) ?> >
                </div>  
            </button>
        </a>
    <?php } ?>

</div>
```

As you can see, I want to insert a linebreak after the `</a>` tag after every 4 loops. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`modulus`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) operator to check if it's your (4n)th loop:

```
<div>
    <?php $i = 0;
    foreach($treatments as $treatment) 
    { 
    ?>
    <a href="/offers/treatmentForm/<?= $treatment->treatment_name ?>">
    <button class = "btn btn-info menu_button">
        <div class = "treatment_box">
            <p><span style="color: rgb(136, 136, 136); font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;"><?=($treatment->treatment_name)?></span></p>
            <img class = "treatment_img" src= <?= ($treatment->icon_url) ?> >
        </div>  
    </button>
</a>
        <?php
        if($i && ($i % 4 === 0)) {
            echo "<br/>";
        }
        $i++;
    } ?>
```

Comment: no, i only have 4 boxes that show up. the other 4 does not show up

Comment: thank u that works!!!! i will accept your answer in 5 minutes because it says that